# How to concatenate Datagridview rows values and store it into one datatable Cell

Tags: c#, datagridview, nullreferenceexception, concatenation

I have a datagridview with one column, i want to concatenate the datagridview rows values and

insert them in one datable cell. This is code i tried

```
private string  concatArticle()
    {
        string libArt = null;

        foreach(DataGridViewRow row1 in ListeArt.Rows)
        {
            if (row1 != null)
            {
                libArt = string.Join(",", row1.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>().Select(c => c.Value.ToString()).ToArray());
            }
        }
        return libArt;
    }
```

and this is the code of inserting values:

```
SqlCommand CmdService = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO BonCommande (NumeroBon, LibArticle, Quantite, DateBon)" +
                    "VALUES (@NumeroBon, @LibArticle, @Quantite, @DateBon)", con4);

                CmdService.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NumeroBon", numeroBonTextBox.Text);
                CmdService.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LibArticle", concatArticle());
                CmdService.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantite",  Convert.ToInt32(quantiteTextBox.Text));
                CmdService.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateBon", Convert.ToDateTime(dateBonDateTimePicker.Text));

                CmdService.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

But when i execute this code i got this error message

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Where is the error??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your textboxes have values ?

Comment: on which line you are getting error

Comment: yes there is values in rows

Comment: the error is here: libArt = string.Join(",", row1.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>().Select(c => c.Value.ToString()).ToArray());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
libArt +=  string.Join(",", row1.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>().Where(c => c.Value != null).Select(c => c.Value.ToString()).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

The value in your cell is `null`

Do a null check first:

```
string.Join(",", row1.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>().Where( c => c.Value != null ).Select( c => c.Value.ToString()).ToArray());
```

Comment: Check the string that generates, apparently is not valid for your parameter. You'll have to debug this

Comment: When i tried your code the error disappear but nothing is inserted in BonCommande table( all values inserted except LibArticle) where is the error??

Comment: i guess that the cell value of LibArticle in the grid is null, so the parameter is also null. debug it

Comment: Debug why the sqlparameter is null

Comment: Sorry i haven't understand you can you explain more

Comment: You're concatArticle method returns a string that you use for the @LibArticle sql parameter. Appararently you suspect some value being set in this parameter. But this doesnt happen. Debug the concatArticle  method what value is generated and why the sqlstatement you're using does not contain the value of the grid.

Comment: Ah thanks for explanation, i do it and i found that concatArticle returns null value, i don't know why !!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
private string  concatArticle()
{
    string libArt = string.Join(", ", ListeArt.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>()
                   .Select(i => i.Cells["yourColumnName"].Value.ToString()).ToArray());
    return libArt;
}
```

Comment: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.